# How to parse output of stdout

Tags: arrays, node.js, exec, stdout, child-process

For example if execute in nodejs child process something like:

```
exec("find /path/to/directory/ -name '*.txt'", callback);
```

How can i parse the streamed output in my callback function to an array to get something like so?

```
['file-1.txt', 'file-2.txt', 'file-3.txt', ...]
```

The current output is like following:

```
path/to/file-1.txt
path/to/file-2.txt
path/to/file-3.txt
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: what parameters does callback returns here??

Comment: function callback(error, stdout, stderr) { ... }

The returned output looks like so: 

`path/to/file1.txt` 

`path/to/file1.txt`

Comment: The returned output of the callback looks like so: 
`path/to/file1.txt` <br/>
`path/to/file2.txt` <br/>
`path/to/file3.txt`

Comment: This might help you-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196261/command-line-stdout-to-array-in-nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("find /path/to/directory -name '*.txt'", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        // handle error
    } else {
        var fileNames = stdout.split('\n').filter(String).map((path) => {
            return path.substr(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        });
        console.log(fileNames); // [ 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt' ]
    }
});
```

or

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("ls /path/to/directory | grep .txt", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        // handle error
    } else {
        var fileNames = stdout.split(/[\r\n|\n|\r]/).filter(String);
        console.log(fileNames); // [ 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt' ]
    }
});
```